# How to delay background animation

Tags: css, animation

I want that the background animation I have set will start in delay.

Here is the fiddle link: [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/p4wj23zr/1/#&togetherjs=IghAKcuMfa)

Here is the css code:

```
.loginButton {
    width: 92%;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #4dbcb8 !important;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 132px;
    color: #14192f !important;
    border-radius: 3px !important;
    font-size: 12pt !important;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.loginButton:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    transition: background .7s ease-out;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 50%, #4dbcb8 50%);
    background-position: right bottom;
    background-size: 200% 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a second time parameter as the delay time:

```
transition: background .7s .5s ease-out;
```

This will cause a 500ms delay.

Comment: That's the right answer, thank you @Hossein Maktoobian

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your .loginButton CSS:

```
animation-delay: 2s;
```

Comment: Since it's not exactly an animation this is not working. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
 div {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: red;
 position: relative;
-webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
 -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 animation: mymove 5s infinite;
 animation-delay: 2s;
 }

 /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 @-webkit-keyframes mymove {
 from {left: 0px;}
 to {left: 200px;}
 } 

 @keyframes mymove {
 from {left: 0px;}
 to {left: 200px;} 
  }

Html 

 <div>
  </div>
```

Please check this link:http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation-delay